# restore $0 or $BASH_SOURCE after it is modified by the cluster

Tags: bash, shell-script, cluster, slurm

I am using a shared SLURM cluster. I am trying to get the path of the bash script from inside the script itself.

There is already an excellent thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/get-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within-the-script-itself. Unfortunately, none of those solutions work for me. They work when I execute the bash script normally, but not when I submit the script as a job. I tried `$BASH_SOURCE`, `$0`, `$_`, and  `readlink /proc/$$/fd/255`. They all return something like `/cm/local/apps/slurm/var/spool/jobXXXXXX/slurm_script`, which is a path auto-generated by SLURM and has nothing to do with the script I submitted. I doubt there are any other solutions that directly answer my question that are not already mentioned, but is there maybe some way to override whatever the cluster is doing? Can I somehow restore standard bash behavior?

Comment: It seems to me like you *have* recovered the name of the script: `/cm/local/apps/slurm/var/spool/jobXXXXXX/slurm_script`. What were you expecting instead, and why does it have to be different?

Comment: No. That is some location used by SLURM. I am going to clarify the question.

Comment: Why do you think that is *not* the path of the script that's executing?

Comment: Because I know the exact script I am executing.

Comment: I don't use slurm, but it's conceivable to me that the system would copy the source script to a worker node in some sort of spooling directory for that node to execute it. Sounds like you might have different expectations?

Comment: SLURM _copies_ your script. On a SLURM cluster, you may not even _have_ a home directory, so the working directory may well be at another path than what you would see when you run your script locally.

Comment: How do you submit the job, exactly?

Comment: sbatch ... myscript.sh

Comment: I've gone in a circle now, so I may have to give up, but -- you start off [knowing the path of your script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498844/restore-0-or-bash-source-after-it-is-modified-by-the-cluster?noredirect=1#comment918412_498844) and then you find the new location when run by slurm, but now you want to know the original location?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I did not expect SLURM to actually copy and rename my script, but that may be indeed what is happening. If I use `--wrap`, it is executed in place.

Comment: What do you need `$BASH_SOURCE` for in your script?  ... and what does not currently work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved in the comments.

To summarize: It turns out that I did not properly diagnose the initial problem. SLURM did not modify `$BASH_SOURCE` or `$0`. I assumed it simply executed my script, but it actually copied my script to a new location (`/cm/local/apps/slurm/var/spool/jobXXXXXX/slurm_script`). To get the behavior I expected, I submitted the job with the `--wrap` parameter which wraps the specified command string in a shell script.